# Single that emits a value that passed function returned

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I want a Single that calls a certain function and then completes with the value that function has returned.

The following is something similar:

```
Single.fromCallable(this::func);
```

The problem with that is that it calls this::func every time a subscriber is added. So if this::func counts calls that single would return 3 to a third subscriber it gets.

I see that as a problem, because, what if this::func were a long running operation.

And I don't get it, does that mean that Single::onComplete has been called twice? Which I thought it was impossible, and it doesn't make sense, because, how can something complete twice?

And since I'm an Android programmer Single::fromFuture doesn't work here, is there some alternative to it?

I will demonstrate my problem with the following example:

```
class SingleFromCallableTest {

    int funcCalls = 0;

    int func(){
        return funcCalls++;
    }

    @Test
    public void run(){
        Single<Integer> source = Single.fromCallable(this::func);
        source.subscribe(System.out::println);  // prints 1
        source.subscribe(System.out::println);  // prints 2
    }
}
```

IMO, second subscriber shouldn't have been called because Single should succed just once IMO.
Just like with SingleSubject, once you call onSuccess, it cannot succed again.

If `Single.fromCallable` would work the way it think it should, than, in the previouse example, `source` could have completed even before the first subscriber subscribed, which means that, only the following way of subscribing would make sense:

```
Single.fromCallable(this::func).subscribe(System.out.println);
```

But actually, maybe even then it's possible not to catch a value emited by single, maybe that's way this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method #fromCallable is a factory and will return a new Single every time. On every subscription you will subscribe to a new Single. Therefore the function will be invoked for every subscriber. If you want to cache the value, you would use #cache operator. Please have a look at provided two tests.

The test 'notCached' will invoke the function for each subscription. The test 'cached' will invoke the function only one time. If you want to share the result, just re-use create Single#fromCallable with #cache operator.

Environment

```
dependencies {
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'
compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0'
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0")
testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0")
```

Tests

```
@Test
void notCached() throws Exception {
    Callable<Integer> mock = mock(Callable.class);

    when(mock.call()).thenReturn(10);

    Single<Integer> integerSingle = Single.fromCallable(mock);

    Disposable subscribe1 = integerSingle.subscribe();
    Disposable subscribe2 = integerSingle.subscribe();

    verify(mock, times(2)).call();
}

@Test
void cached() throws Exception {
    Callable<Integer> mock = mock(Callable.class);

    when(mock.call()).thenReturn(10);

    Single<Integer> integerSingle = Single.fromCallable(mock).cache();

    Disposable subscribe1 = integerSingle.subscribe();
    Disposable subscribe2 = integerSingle.subscribe();
    Disposable subscribe3 = integerSingle.subscribe();
    Disposable subscribe4 = integerSingle.subscribe();

    verify(mock, times(1)).call();
}
```

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: If you want to gain full inside in rxjava you might look at this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do. I highly recommend it.